# Yii - Behaivor chekcbox

Tags: php, checkbox, yii, behavior

I have the following problem that seems to be basic: I have a HTML, to some checkbox, this:

```
<? php echo $ form> checkBox ($ certificate, 'a', array ('id' => 'a')); ?>
```

When sending the POST, if the checkbox is not with the check, send 0, and if checkbox sends 1, the same HTML I have this one:

```
<? php echo $ form> checkBox ($ certificate, 'head', array ('id' => 'head')); ?>
```

With this last time, if the checkbox is not check sent 0, but when to check, send nothing. So far I do not understand this behavior, can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Without more details on the property types of your "certificate" model (whether they are strings or integers), I can only infer that the reason you get nothing for selecting the "head" checkbox is that its type is not compatible with booleans.

If your "head" type is set to string, try setting it to integer.

Comment: Part of the model looks like this ::

Certificates.php
public function rules()
 {
  
  return array(
   array('a, head', 'integerOnly'=>true),
   array('a, cabeza', 'on'=>'search'),
  );
 }

Obviously my model has defined much more fields , but I leave these as they are of the same type behaving differently. In my table the two fields are the type INT

Comment: So for all intents and purposes, the "a" and "head" attributes are exactly the same thing except for the name?  That is very odd then.

The only thing that seems missing however is 'numerical' in your rule:  `array('a, head', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true)`.  Maybe you left it out on purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved the problem. With the checkBox have the labelEx, For a reason, I put:

`<?php echo $form->labelEx($certificate,'head', array('id' => 'head')); ?>` 
`<?php echo $form->checkBox($certificate,'head', array('id' => 'head')); ?>`

with this, the POST send the value check, I don't understand the reason, but work. I think if is a bug in this component, I don't know.